# Determine if a set of points in a n dimensional set that are closer to point v1 than to point v2 form a half-space

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following problem:

**Consider two points, $v_1,v_2 ∈ R^n$. Show that there exist $c ∈ R^n and d ∈ R$ (and find them!) such that $${x : ||x−v1||_2 ≤||x−v2||_2}={x : c^Tx≤d}$$
Thus, you are showing that the set of points in Rn that are closer to point $v_1$ than to point $v_2$, form a half-space.**

I am just getting back into this sort of math so I am having some trouble understanding what the equation is asking. From the statement underneath I can infer that I need to find the half-way point (hyperplane) between the two points, and then show the points that are on the $v_1$ side of the hyperplane. So thinking it should be something like:

$$x ∈ R^n : a^Tx < b$$

Also if someone could explain the equation version of the question that would be awesome, specifically the 2 subscript and why x - 2. I've also been wondering why we use a transform when discussing a hyperplane instead of dot product

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!. That would be good that you use Latex. You have a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). What have you tried? Can you look at the case $n = 2$? [Wikipedia Line segment bisector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector) should help!

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, edited the question with my thoughts as well as some additional clarifying questions. Also thanks for the LaTeX tip...total game changer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the geometric interpretation in $3$-dimensional space. For a concrete example, suppose that the two initial points were $\vec v_1 = (-3, 1, 2)$ and $\vec v_2 = (1, -5, 4)$. Then intuitively the boundary for the points closer to $\vec v_1$ than $\vec v_2$ (i.e.: the locus of points equidistant from both points) should form a $2$-dimensional plane, perpendicular to the line connecting the two points, and halfway between them.

Finding the normal vector of the plane (in the direction of $\vec v_2$), we have:
$$
\vec c = \vec v_2 - \vec v_1 = (4, -6, 2)
$$
So the plane has the form $4x - 6y + 2z = d$. This plane must pass through the midpoint, namely:
$$
\vec m = \frac{1}{2}(\vec v_1 + \vec v_2) = (-1, -2, 3)
$$
so that $d = 4(-1) - 6(-2) + 2(3) = 14$. Thus, the half-space is:
$$
S = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid (4, -6, 2)^\top(x, y, z) \leq 14 \}
$$
We can verify that $\vec v_1, \vec m \in S$ while $\vec v_2 \notin S$. Now generalize!